# Can I install a new hob, or will I need a larger circuit?

Tags: kitchens

I want to swap a ceramic hob for another model.
My current set is: oven and a hob rated at 2075+6000=8075W in total ,they go through a 32Amp Circuit breaker, the oven is plugged to the wall, the hob is hard wired.
The new hob is 6500W, 2075+6500=8575W this should be fine considering circuit diversity. Is this a straight job (wire the new hob) or should I get an electrician to actually upgrade the circuit breaker?

Comment: 8575 watts at 220 volts is 38.9 amperes. More than a 32 amp breaker.

Comment: Not familiar with foreign codes, but the US NEC requires (in a footnote to a table, no less) that the amperage ratings of the hob and oven be summed and used as the branch-circuit load for the case where a single hob and up to 2 ovens are tapped from a single branch circuit.

Answer (score -1):

Straight up. If you only work on the cooktop and do not go into the wall circuits, fair game.

Comment: Ta, I can't up-vote since I'm not registered, but.. Up-vote